# org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond: Rollback data

Tags: java, database, web-services, httpclient, rollback

I have a synchronization process between 2 Web-services A and B. 
+ A update database and send data to B and wait to commit
+ B receive data from B, execute, update database and send result to A to commit.
With a huge number of data, B take a long time to process and return org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException The target server failed to respond. So B update data but A has exception and rollback. How can i handle this problem.
Many thanks!

Comment: With no specifc details and no actual code it's not clear what kind of help you are expecting to get, beyond "make sure your firewall(s) aren't interfering with the network traffic".

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Jim Garrison. The firewall isn't the problem because it works fine with small data. All i need is the method to increase connection time then A can wait for B longer :)